# How to search some word in python help() built-in function result?

Tags: python, docstring

Sometimes I need search some thing inside some python library docs that I have installed  and I always use help() built-in function but I would like to know if there are some way to search inside this content or even better, without need to open a python terminal. I really would like to know some clean way to do this (linux based), avoiding pipes or something like this that I already know.  There are some library or external useful to share with us?

Comment: Do you want a way to search all the docstrings in one go, or just the docstring for a class or method you name?

Comment: At least the same info that I can get using help() inside the interpreter. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In shell:

```
pydoc modulename | grep the-word
```

Example

```
$ pydoc os | grep chmod
chmod(...)
    chmod(path, mode)
fchmod(...)
    fchmod(fd, mode)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's interesting. I did not know it, but I can not use if I want to get info about a library installed in my venv, as pymongo for example. Or I can?

Comment: Sure you can. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html)